# mongodb query nested array with date field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

this is my document .

```
"calendar": {
        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a3b8",
        "hotel": "5cd02fe495be1a4f48150447",
        "calendar": [
            {
                "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a413",
                "date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z",
                "rooms": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a415",
                        "room": "5cd17d82ca56fe43e24ae5d3",
                        "price": 10,
                        "remaining": 8,
                        "reserved": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a414",
                        "room": "5cd17db6ca56fe43e24ae5d4",
                        "price": 12,
                        "remaining": 8,
                        "reserved": 0
                    },
                 {
                        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a34",
                        "room": "5cd17db6ca45fe43e24ae5e7",
                        "price": 0,
                        "remaining": 0,
                        "reserved": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
   }
```

and this is my shema:

```
const calendarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    hotel: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Hotel",
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "City"
    },
    calendar: [
        {
            date: Date,
            rooms: [
                {
                    room: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                        ref: "Room",
                        required: true
                    },
                    price: {
                        type: Number
                    },
                    remaining: {
                        type: Number
                    },
                    reserved: {
                        type: Number
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

First of all, as you can see my calendar stores `hotelId` and `CityId` and included another calendar that contains some objects. There is nothing fancy here. The query has two conditions as below:

**1.Our specific filter is located whole dates between startDate and endDate**

**2.Mentioned filter only shows the room's prices and remaining ( Not included zero num ).**

And after injecting this conditions, query must return only the rooms that are matched with my filter. 
I tried some query but the outcome is not my result .

```
db.calendars.find({ 
  'calendar': { 
      '$elemMatch': { 
           date: { 
             '$lt': ISODate("2019-05-09T09:37:24.005Z"), 
             '$lt': ISODate("2019-06-05T09:37:24.005Z")
           },
           "rooms.$.price": { '$gt': 0 },
           "rooms.$.remaining": { '$gt': 0 }
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not THAT easy as you describe, this cannot be done with just a find assuming you want to project ONLY (and all) the rooms that match.

However with an aggregate this is possible, it would look like this:

```
db.calendars.aggregate([
    {
        $project:
            {
                "rooms": {
                    $filter: {
                        input: {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$calendar",
                                "as": "cal",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [
                                        {
                                            $and: [{$gt: ["$$cal.date", ISODate("2019-05-09T09:37:24.005Z")]},
                                                {$lt: ["$$cal.date", ISODate("2019-06-05T09:37:24.005Z")]},]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "rooms": {
                                                "$filter": {
                                                    "input": "$$cal.rooms",
                                                    "as": "room",
                                                    "cond": {
                                                        $and: [{"$gt": ["$$room.price", 0]},
                                                            {"$gt": ["$$room.remaining", 0]}]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            date: "$$cal.date"
                                        },
                                        null
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        as: 'final',
                        cond: {$size: {$ifNull: ["$$final.rooms", []]}}
                    }
                },

            }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "rooms.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: tnx for your answer, but it complaining about $size : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing"

Comment: @tom-slabbaert i have a similar document and requirement, your query very useful, but `price` and `remaining` conditions check first date rooms, in data from 01/02/2019 to 05/02/2019 and price on 03/02/2019 is 0, should return false, but return calendar, but if this happen in first date `01/02/2019`, conditions worked.

Comment: @omid i'm sorry i didn't quiet understand, you need to do the same query with minor differences?

Comment: @tomslabbaert yes, see this question please,  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850607/mongodb-advance-complex-multi-filter-query